# Show Data from sqlDatabase to listview or gridview

Tags: android, xamarin

i'm beginner in xamarin projects. I want to get data from my sql database and show them in a listview or gridview. First of all will i use sqlLite for doing this. And second is there any easy tutorial which  expains how will i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn Xamarin is running samples (and deploy them to devices or simulator) from Github in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio.  Given that it's not recommended to paste Github links, you can visit Github and search form Xamarin.  I don't know what platform you want to develop for.  I recommend Xamarin-forms.  And there's a sample for SQLite (a to-do app).

Answer (score 1):

check this out.this may help you
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1090451/Xamarin-Android-App-Using-SQLite-and-Custom-List